# Python : Why list out of index error appears if returning but not when printing

Tags: python, list, count

Hi while i was solving challenge on pythonprinciples.com i've met an error.

Challenge content:

Define a function named all_equal that takes a list and checks whether all elements in the list are the same.

For example, calling all_equal([1, 1, 1]) should return True.

Solution which is throwing an error:

```
def all_equal(nestedList):
   return len(nestedList) == nestedList.count(nestedList[0])

print(all_equal([1, 1, 1]))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pyrunnerSDobDKmo/code.py", line 7, in 
    result = all_equal([])
  File "/tmp/pyrunnerSDobDKmo/usercode.py", line 2, in all_equal
    return (len(nestedList) == nestedList.count(nestedList[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When i try this solution on my own pc (not online interpreter) or if print instead of return an error is not thrown.
So is this error python version dependent or maybe there is another reason?

Comment: `nestedList` is empty, so `nestedList[0]` is out of bounds.

Comment: When you tried on your own PC, did you try with an empty list?

Comment: I suggest looking at what the set function does, then think how you can approach the problem.

Comment: @barmar i've tried :

print(all_equal([1, 1, 1]))

same on pc as on online interpreter

Comment: That's not an empty list. Try `print(all_equal([]))` on your PC.

Comment: You get the error when you try to submit it as a solution online because the website checks your code for more test cases than just `nestedList = [1, 1, 1]`. One of these cases is `nestedList = []`, which is what causes your code to break

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for explanation, everything makes sens now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works if the list is **not empty**.
Something like

```
def all_equal(nestedList):
   return len(nestedList) == 0 or len(nestedList) == nestedList.count(nestedList[0])
```

should work.